# Matlab: Free memory of class objects

Tags: class, matlab, memory

I recently wrote some code using Matlab's OOP. In each class object I save some measurement data as a property and define the methods for evaluating them. With an average data set one single class object uses about 32 MB of memory.
Now I am writing a GUI that should process these objects.

In the first step I load a set of objects from a saved .mat-file (about 200 objects, 2GB on harddisk) and store them in the handles struct. They fill the RAM and use about 6-7 GB, when loaded. This is no problem.

But if I close the GUI, it seems that I can't free the used memory.
I tried different approaches with no success.

Setting the data fields to "empty" in the destructor of the class:

```
function delete(obj)
    obj.timeVector = [];
    obj.valueVector = [];
end
```

Trying to free it in the figure_CloseRequestFcn:

```
function figure_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    handles.data = [];
    handles = rmfield(handles,'data');
    guidata(hObject,handles);
    clear handles;
    pack; %Matlab issues a warning, that pack could only 
          %be used from the command line, but that did
          %not work either
    delete(hObject);
end
```

Any ideas, besides closing Matlab every time after working with the GUI?

Comment: Are you sure the memory is still blocked, and not just displayed to be occupied? So if you use a normal amount of memory, will you run out? Furthermore I could only think of `clear all`, but don't have too much hope there.

Comment: So I assume it's just reserved by Matlab, but if another program needs more RAM, Matlab sets it free? I tried to quit the GUI, starting another RAM intensive program and after stopping, Matlab seems to set free some of its reserved memory (see link). I just was confused because normally after a GUI/script/function quits, the memory usage of Matlab drops to its normal, "idle" usage.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/zWrcu.png

Comment: What is the result of a `memory` command before, during, and after you use the GUI?

Comment: I couldn't format the output in this comment, so I made a screenshot. i.stack.imgur.com/Box1R.png
EDIT: If I run the GUI a second time, without closing Matlab in between, the loading takes much longer and the `memory` command gives: Maximum possible array: 6137 MB Memory used by MATLAB: 11456 MB That is more than before, so Matlab doesn't clean up.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting, got to get used to the comment style... here is another (better) screenshot. http://i.stack.imgur.com/AajC3.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer in the Matlab Bug Report Center. Seems to exist since R2011b.

**Summary**

Storing objects in MAT-files can cause a memory leak and prevent the object class from being cleared

**Description**

After storing an instance of a class, 'MyClass', in a MAT-file, calling clear classes may result in the warning:

Warning: Objects of 'MyClass' class exist. Cannot clear this class or any of its superclasses.

This warning persists, even if you have cleared all instances of the class in the workspace.
The warning may occur for one MAT-file format, and not for another.

**Workaround**

Under some circumstances, switching to a different MAT-file format may eliminate the warning.

http://www.mathworks.ch/support/bugreports/857319

Edit:
I tried older formats for saving, but this does not work either. I get an "Error closing file" (http://www.mathworks.ch/matlabcentral/answers/18098-error-using-save-error-closing-file). So Matlab does not support saving class objects that well. I will have to live with the memory issues then and restart Matlab after every use of the GUI.

Comment: Have you considered overloading `load` and `save` for your class? save only the properties of the class (the actual data), then create a constructor that given this struct builds the entire class instance?

Comment: @Shai I did not think of that, but the data structure is: `struct.classObject.data`. And there is additional information in the struct itself, besides the different types of class objects. I would have to either overload the save/load for a `struct`, or write an extra function to decompose the whole data structure into single parts and compose them again. I think this would be too much effort, because it's pretty complex. But thanks for the idea.

Comment: What happens if you do `struct( myClassInstance )`?

Comment: @Shai I wrote my own `save` and `load` functions now. `save` parses the superior struct for class objects. These are then converted to `structs` like you suggested. The load function calls the different class constructors and rebuilds the whole superior structure. I added a simple version control, so that the user is warned, if he loads data that doesn't fit to a newer version of the class definitions. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

Based on your `memory` screenshots, there is definitely memory that is not being cleared.  There is a small chance that you have found a fundamental flaw in Matlab's garbage collection, but it is much more likely that the ~6Gigs of memory resident data is still actually available via some series of links.  Based on personal experience, here are a few ways that memory which you thought was cleared can still be available:

- Timer objects:  If one of the callback functions of a timer references a this data (or a copy), then that data is still available.  You need to call `deleted(t)` on that timer.
- Persistent variables in functions:  I often cache data in a persistent variable within a function, this clearly allows access to that data in the future, so it will not be cleared.  You need to call `clear FUNCTIONNAME` to clear associated persistent variables.
- In GUI objects, as either data or within callback functions:  The figures and any persistents need to be cleared.
- Any static methods or constant attributes in classes which can retain data.  These can either be cleared individually within the class, or by force using `clear CLASSNAME`.

Some tips for finding stale link to data (again, based on personal mistakes)

- Look at the exact number of bytes being lost after each call, using the `x=memory;` call to get an exact count.  Is it consistent?  Is it a number that you recognize?  Sometimes I can find the leak after realizing that it is exactly 238263232 bytes, therefore a 29782904 double array, which must be from function xyz.
- See which classes are actually being deleted.  Within your `delete(obj)` function add a detailed display or which objects are being deleted, and by inference, which are not.  For a given non-deleted object, where could it be reference from?  You should not need to clear data in the `delete(obj)` function like you are doing, Matlab should handle that for you.  Use the `delete` function instead as a debugging tool.

Comment: I narrowed it further down. It isn't the GUI itself, but the saving/loading. I just created the objects from scratch in the workspace and just saved them with the `-v7.3 format`, because of the file size. Clearing the workspace works fine, the destructor is called for each object and the memory is freed. After reloading the same objects from hdd, clearing does not work, giving the warning: Objects of 'ClassName' class exist.  Cannot clear this class or any of its superclasses. Using `delete(classObj)` for each object calls the destructor but doesn't free memory either.

Answer (score -1):

Matlab has a [garbage collector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) so you don't need to manually manage memory. After closing the GUI, all the memory will be freed except for what is in your workspace. You can clear the workspace variables using [`clear`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/clear.html).

One thing I've noticed on Windows (not sure about other platforms) is that Matlab's GUI sometimes retains extra memory (maybe 100 MB, but not multiple GB like you are seeing). Simply minimizing and then restoring the GUI will free this excess memory.